# unable use rebase command

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to squash the git commits with following command

**$ git rebase -i HEAD~3**

But after running above command I am facing following error:

**fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'**

Comment: What is the output of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph`? (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `invalid upstream <xxx>` message when `<xxx>` doesn't match anything known to git.

In your case : if you are on a fresh branch with only 3 commits, `HEAD~3` (the 3rd parent of current commit) does not exist, hence the message.

---

To squash commits together, you can use :

```
git reset --soft <sha of the first commit>  # or : git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit --amend
```

If you want to use `git rebase`, there is a special [`--root` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---root) to say "rebase the whole branch" :

```
git rebase -i --root
```